# IE8 force refreshes the webpage using compatibility view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm using a simple JavaScript method to open colorbox on button click & it works fine in all browsers except IE8 where it will refresh the page push browser in compatibility mode. Here is sample of my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PopulateReferral() {
        $.colorbox({ inline: true, width: "775px", height: "800px", href: "#divPartialReferralUpdate" });
    }
</script>

<div id="divPartialReferralUpdate" style="margin:10px;">
        <div id="divCurrentNotes" style="max-height:300px; width:660px; overflow:scroll"></div>
</div>
```

If, I remove overflow tag from style on div, it works fine. Is there any conflict between colorbox & overflow? Any work around to fix div height?

Comment: This is hard to debug without a test case.

Comment: I have also experienced this type of behaviour where IE8 will automatically go to comp mode. In my case, I changed some css and it was ok. You could try overflow auto but I am not 100% sure if IE8 will provide scrollbar or not

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but you should have a `;` after `overflow:scroll`.

Comment: i changed my code to overflow:auto instead of scroll & it worked. Thanks a lot @Huangism . Please answer the question, I will go ahead & accept it :)

Comment: glad it worked, I know ie8 can be a huge pain in the butt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also experienced this type of behaviour where IE8 will automatically go to comp mode. In my case, I changed some css and it was ok.

You could try overflow auto but I am not 100% sure if IE8 will provide scrollbar or not.

```
<div id="divCurrentNotes" style="max-height:300px; width:660px; overflow:auto;"></div>
```